# jQuery.ajax returns jsonp instead of json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I have a simple ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
       url: u, type: "POST", dataType: "json",
       data: data,
       success: function (d) { response($.map(d, function (o) { return { label: o.Text, value: o.Text, id: o.Id} })); }
});
```

It is part of an tb autocomplete that does not work on only one view. 
The reason it does not work is that instead of json, it makes jsonp request (by sniffing I saw that it calls passed url with `?callback=jQueryxxxxxxxxx`), and success function is never called because jquery packs it into anonymous function whose name is passed in callback argument, and server returns standard json (I don't want to use jsonp as it is POST request and NOT cross-domain request). I checked, both current view url and this `u` for ajax url argument are on `http://localhost:8080/myapp/areax/...`, so I don't see why jQuery makes JSONP request here.

**EDIT:**

View on which this does not work has url request is made is like this:
http://hostname:8080/AreaName/Report/ViewReport
and u parameter of ajax is like */AreaName/MyAutoComplete/Search*, so complete url to which autocomplete is made is like
http://hostname:8080/AreaName/MyAutoComplete/Search?callback=jQuery151013129048690121925_1327065146844

Server's response looks like this:

```
[{"Id":2,"Text":"001"},{"Id":7,"Text":"002"}]
```

I know it is not jsonp, for that it should be

```
<script>
 jQuery151013129048690121925_1327065146844([{"Id":2,"Text":"001"},{"Id":7,"Text":"002"}]);
</script>
```

But I want to make normal json request, not jsonp.

**UPDATE**

Weirdest thing of all (I'm starting to think it is a bug in jQUery v1.5.1 which is used on project) is that when I remove `dataType: "json"`, it makes a normal json request :)

So, instead of how to make json request, now I will accept an explanation to why this works as expected (and the one with dataType:"json" does not):

```
$.ajax({
       url: u, type: "POST",
       data: data,
       success: function (d) { response($.map(d, function (o) { return { label: o.Text, value: o.Text, id: o.Id} })); }
});
```

Comment: Can you  please show the complete url including any parameters?

Comment: Can you try out when 'u' is relative to your current domain. For example: /myapp/areax/...

Comment: is it a cross domain request? may be the same host but different port? It's strange dude...

Comment: I have added more info in edit.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't works with dataType:json. As per documentation http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ even if you don't specify dataType:JSON it will infer thats its json..

Comment: Make sure you return proper JSON from the server: content_type='application/json; charset=UTF-8' Charset part is important.

Comment: Yes, Nakul, I'm sure, that is why I wrote that I'm thinking it is a bug. And @ustun, it is not problem in server, if you read my question, you will see that jQuery makes a JSONP request and expects result to call callback function. That is the problem, result from server is irrelevant once the jsonp request is sent, it is not processed unless IS a jsonp result, which is not and I don't want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the bug here : http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8118

You are probably using jquery-validation plugin. Jquery-validation plugin is not compatible with jQuery 1.5 and the conflict causes the kind of issue you are having here.

If the problem is not specifically due to jquery-validation plugin, check if you have any other jquery plugin that might not be compatible with jQuery 1.5

Comment: Yes, this is exact issue I encountered. As I suspected, it was the bug in jQuery :) Thanks!